# get changes by other users in MS Access

Tags: javascript, database, ms-access, real-time

Is this possible?
To know data changed by other users in realtime without requery or refresh on MS Access.

I'm developing user forms in HTML & Javascript and using MS Access as back-end DB.

Three or four users always keep opening the form.

I want to refresh and display other user's changes into the form in real-time, like SQLserver's SqlNotificationRequest or Ajax with php.

I allowed only using MS Access and HTML with JS on intranet, due to an authority.

Is there no way but using timer function with refresh or requery in JS?

Comment: Too many questions

Comment: Not from Access. It will be up to your frontend (client) to refresh data.

Comment: Frontend is html & js. So I think the only way to reflesh data real-time Is using timer-like function which calls refresh. And set the interval shorter.     right?

Comment: Can you use  some js library like node-watch to 'watch' the changes on your database and then send info to your clients using sockets?

Comment: I hardly know about node-watch. I'll check and try it. Thanks Gustav and Duatis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in real time; you will have to fake it. Decide what is an acceptable lag in the information update (5 seconds? 30 seconds?) and set up a timer on your front end.

When the data is modified on your database is there logging/audit? Do you keep a timestamp? If yes, you can use that to check for new changes. If not, just create a single record, single field table to store the last modification timestamp. Or if you have a generic parameter or global values stable, add one more record there. Make sure anything on your front end that alters data updates this timestamp field.

Then your front end's timer function can check the last update timestamp and compare it with its own last update timestamp (which you stored locally on the previous timer event) and see if it needs to refresh the data or not.